# How to securely send data to the controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have basketball match details page "single.blade.php" and a page to purchase "payment.blade.php". In the match details page, the user can select through a select how many tickets want for each type. For example the user can select 2 tickets for the central bench and 2 for the left side bench and then click "Next".

When the user click "Next", the quantities for each ticket type selected by the user are stored in an array so that is possible to show that info in the payment.blade.php page.

This is working fine with the code below.

But how to pass also the price?

In the match details page I get the price of each ticket type with "`{{$ticket->showPrice()}}`" as you can see below.

**Match details page has the types of tickets listed and for each one there is a select menu so the user can select how many tickets want for each one:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('matchs.payment', ['id' => $match->id, 'slug' => $match->slug])}}">

                <select name=type[{{ $ticket->title }}]>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                    ...
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Payment Page"/>
    </form>
</ul>
```

If I give a name to the span like `<span name="typePrice">X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>` in the controller "dd($request->all());" is not showing the price, it only shows the types and quantities, it dont shows the price:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => ""
  "type" => array:2 [▼
    "center bench" => "2"
    "lateral bench" => "1"
      ]
]
```

Controller:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function storeQuantity(Request $request){

        dd($request->all());
        $selectedRtypes = $request->rtype;

        return view('events.registration')->with('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
    }
}
```

Do you know why the price is not passed to the controller? But also do you know if this approach is ok in terms of security? Because in the match details page where the ticket types are listed and also the price of each ticket type the user can change in the source code  the price right? And then the controller will receive a incorrect price and pass a incorrect price to the payment page.

And this is also valid for the quantity types and ticket type names, the user can change in the source code the ticket type name for a name that dont exist, also he can add for example quantity "1000" that should not be possible.

Do you know how to handle this context, how to only allow to send correct data to the controller?

Comment: Protip: You cannot trust data sent by the client. Never ever. Letting the client submit the ticket price is silly. You'll end up like [BKK / T-Systems](https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/25/hungarian-hacker-arrested-for-pressing-f12/). After submitting the form, just repeat whatever you did to display the prices in the first place (presumably a database query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were building this application I would not allow the user to edit the price at all. I would store (whether in the session or database) the seat type and the quantity for each. I wouldn't pass the payment information via the request. I would calculate the price based on the seat cost multiplied by the quantity and store it in the session/database. I would only give the user a read only view of the price.

When you get to the payment page you'd need to pull the information directly from the session or database.

It's the only safe way to do it as if you pass information via the request relating to price, it's open to being abused.

Comment: Thanks, but Im not understanding. For example the process for a user to buy tickets is like this "https://ibb.co/iGMCSH", it has 4 pages. In the first the user select the ticket type and quantities, then he goes to a page that should present the request summary and the user needs to enter some data like name, email, etc, then he goes to a page to select the payment method and then he goes to the page where he does the payment. In this question Im talking about the first two pages of the process.

Comment: And the user can´t change the price, the price appears static on the details page, but maybe is possible a user change the price in the source code and is necessary to handle that. But using sessions is not the same issue? Instead of store in an array in the storeQuantity() method if is stored is not the same issue? The user can change in the source code the values and that values are stored in the session, so is not the same issue?

Comment: You must not  use the price variables you showed to user for anything on server side. User selects seats - you pull info about price from db. User says - ok I want  to pay for those seats - you pull the  price from dB again when you send user input to card processing. This avoids user modifying price so that he pays 0 for tickets.

Comment: Thanks, so the code in the question PaymentController is ok right? And its only necessary  to add in this storeQuantity() method the price from db? And also for example in the form where the user can select the quantities in the source code he can change the name of ticket types no? Or because the ticket type is inside a span "            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> "  even if the user user change the ticket type name in source code the controller will not receive that incorrect name?